# Hide a submit_tag in Rails 2.3 by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I wanted to have the submit_tag in rails 2.3 hidden by default i.e. get `style="visibility:hidden"` in the html output for the submit_tag. I searched the APIs but wasn't of any help. I tried sth. like

```
<%= submit_tag 'Save', :id=>"submitBtn"+i.to_s, :visibility=>"hidden"%>
```

just in case hoping that it might work. But it didn't work.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `<%= submit_tag 'Save', :style => "display:none" %>`